# Facebook API Metric - how to get: total photo views, comments, share and link click

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, metric

i am trying to get some data via Facebook API. Currently i can get:

- organic impression (Metric: page_impressions_organic)
- organic paid impression (Metric: page_impressions_paid)
- total likes (Metric: page_fans)
- total video views (Metric: page_video_views)

What i also need is:

- total photo views
- total shares
- total link clicks
- total comments

but i do not know how to get it.

Is it possible to get this data via Metric or a different way through the Facebook API? Could you tell me the methods to achieve please?

Thanks